# Why does the "LaTeX error... perhaps a missing item" error pop up when I try to create a phantom (0-space) lemma?

Tags: errors, phantom

I wanted to create a theorem which does not occupy any space yet adds to the theorem counter. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\smash{\begin{thm}\relax \end{thm}}
\end{document}
```

I received this error:

> There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

I do not know how to handle this problem, or if there is a better way to create an "invisible" theorem. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: why don't you simply increase the counter?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Ulrike Fischer, you might want to directly increment the counter as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\addtocounter{thm}{1}
\begin{thm}
  Test.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The  `Perhaps a missing \item` error is thrown if the vertical space command `\addvspace` (which is used around most display objects in LaTeX) is incorrectly used in horizontal mode.

It is possible to get into that state by a badly formed list structure hence the wording, however there are many other ways to get that and also many things (like theorems, or `center` environments) are implemented as one-item lists.

Here `\smash` is like `\mbox` and only accepts horizontal  (LR) material, but you have used a theorem which is a vertical display construct with vertical space and a styled paragraph.